# Tensorflow and Python Anywhere

Tags: python, tensorflow, pythonanywhere

I am trying to use Tensorflow and according to the forums python3.7 is the best. Even though I have created a python3.7 console whenever I run my python file it defaults to a python3.8 interpreter. How can I change it to 3.7.

In addition to this I can't upload model because it and its zip are too large.

How would I go about configuring a Tensorflow compatible env in python anywhere?

Comment: @ThomasWeller How do I use pycharm on pythonanywhere? I didn't know you could use venvs there.

Comment: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs/